# Creating domain models in angular 6 for use in other libraries

Tags: angular6

I have many domain models that consist of an interface and its corresponding class, similar to the example below:

```
export interface ILanguage {
  first: string
  second?: string
}

export class Language {
  first: string = ''
  second?: string
}
```

In angular 5 it was easy just to import each model in the different parts of the programme. However, in angular 6 because of libraries this is not possible. I realise I would have to use libraries.

I would like some suggestions as to best practices or any suggestion as to how this could be accomplished.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the interface/class explicitly in the public_api.ts

```
export * from './lib/<path to class file>
```